# Are Bionicle questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

From 2000 to 2010, The Lego Group had a theme called Bionicle. They were basically action figures, but they had a really elaborate story with books and comics. The characters are organic/robotic.
The stories mostly occur on three different parts of a once-whole planet.

So would Bionicle-related questions be allowed on the Science Fiction and Fantasy site?

Comment: FYI, there is a [Lego.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919/lego) on Area 51, that's should be in beta soon.

Comment: And live now: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the lore, plot, characters, shows, and other story-related aspects: yes.

About where to get sets, prices, or other toy-related aspects: no.

Comment: Cool; thanks! I just hope there's some knowledgeable people with...erm...knowledge on this subject.